# Can we limit 'Security Level' in Secure Channel Protocol (SCP) 02 communication?

Tags: security, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a situation where I want to load and install an applet on card. SCP_02 will be used to perform authentication with ISD or CM. But I want SCP_02 authentication  to be performed only with maximum security, i.e. C-MAC and encryption. No other security level should be allowed by ISD (or by any additional SSD, where required).

Is it possible to achieve this?

---

Expected result with external-authenticate (Ex-Auth) command:

Plain Ex-Auth: `8482000010f7d23150e635fd93d4e5ef76368f3d68`
Expected Response : `6986`

C-MAC Ex-Auth: `8482010010f7d23150e635fd93d4e5ef76368f3d68`
Expected Response : `6986`

Enc + C-MAC Ex-Auth: `8482030010f7d23150e635fd93d4e5ef76368f3d68`
Expected Response : `9000` (authentication successful)

Comment: Note that you should use the Data Encryption Key (DEK) (or was it Key Encryption Key for KEK - I forgot) to additionally protect sensitive information send over the channel.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I don't understand your point. Would you provide more details? If i use additional encryption, how would ISD know ?

Comment: he is refering to the DEK which is used for the PUTKEY command. If you are transfering new sensitive material to the card, you can use another secret key for encryption, that is not the message encryption key. Just look up how the PUTKEY works and decide if this concept is important to you

Comment: @maaren thanks for help but not the antidote I’m looking forward right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no mechanism in the Global Platform specification that matches your needs.
Your two possiblities that I see are:

- use card proprietary settings and conventions
- as I see your other questions which is related to Personalization of applets, you could do the following in your applet:

  1. Select your applet to be personalized
  2. perform init-update and ext-auth against the applet directly and use `SecureChannel.processSecurity()` to redirect the authentication process to the secury domain
  3. check the security Level with `SecureChannel.getSecurityLevel()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Would you please provide more information on first suggestion? How to infuse proprietary settings on card? 
FYI> I am using third party card to load an applet.

Comment: first answer means: read the manual of your card vendor and have a look if he provides additional settings